# Apache mod_rewrite not happening on localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I can't seem to get my head around this. I just pulled down my website files from my server to work on them offline. However, my rewrite conditions are no longer working as expected.

I've been googleing for the last 3 hours and keep coming to these solutions:

1. put garbage in the .htaccess file to make sure it's being read. I did that and got a 500 error so it is.
2. Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled, and I make sure it was listed in php_info(). That's not the problem.

Other than that, I can't figure this thing out.

Here's my .htaccess. All I want to do is remove index.php from my URLs:

```
# Rewrite url no index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Here's my virtual host config at the moment:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin xxxx@gmail.com
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/myapp/public_html/"
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/myapp/public_html/">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
ServerName myapp.local
ErrorLog "logs/myapp.local"
CustomLog "logs/myapp.local" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I'd also like to make it known that rewrite rules seem to work *a bit* when they're in the virtual host config. So something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin xxx@gmail.com
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/myapp/public_html/"
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/myapp/public_html/">
 # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
 RewriteEngine on
 # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
 RewriteRule . index.php

 # ...other settings...
</Directory>
ServerName myapp.local
ErrorLog "logs/myapp.local"
CustomLog "logs/myapp.local" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I had other problems with this though since I have nested applications (one's at / and the other at /app2/). I also seemed to have problems with the !-f condition being ignored and it would rewrite the URLs of my images and css.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use your code like this to remove index.php from the URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /index\.php(.*)\ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

And then in your **head** section of your html add this to fix CSS problem.

```
<base href="http://myapp.local" />
```

Comment: I just tried adding your code to my htaccess file instead of mine, but I'm getting the same results. Any other thoughts?